# How to integrate $\int{\frac{x^2+5}{x^3+3x}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, partial-fractions

How to [integrate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20(x%5E2%2B5)%2F(x%5E3%2B3x)) $$\int{\frac{x^2+5}{x^3+3x}}dx$$

I have computed it in a solver with steps. It uses partial fraction decomposition. And it gets two different denominators even if there exists only one real root: $x^3+3x=x(x^2+3) \Rightarrow x = 0$.
What is the most easy and most common way to solve that integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do partial fractions:

$$\frac{x^2+5}{x(x^2+3)}=\frac Ax+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+3}\implies x^2+5=A(x^2+3)+(Bx+C)x$$

Put now:

$$x=0\implies 5=3A\implies A=\frac53\,,\,\,\text{coeff. of}\;x^2: \; 1=A+B\implies B=-\frac23$$

and finally, comapring coefficients of $\;x\;$ in both sides wer get $\;C=0\;$, so

$$\frac{x^2+5}{x(x^2+3)}=\frac5{3x}-\frac{2x}{3(x^2+3)}$$

Now integrate the above.

Comment: I think there may be a mistake in the partial fraction decomposition: $$\frac{5}{3x}-\frac{2}{3(x^2+3)}=\frac{5x^2+15-2x}{3x(x^2+3)}$$

Comment: can you explain your last step more detailed, please? 
I do not understand where $\frac1{\sqrt3}\int\frac{\frac1{\sqrt3}dx}{1+\left(\frac x{\sqrt3}\right)^2}$ does come from

Comment: @Dave Of course there is: there should be a $\;x\;$ in the second summand. Thanks, editing now.

Comment: @jublikon You don't need that anymore. I edited my answer to fix a typo. Take a peek.

Answer (score 3):

Partial fraction decomposition :

$$\int{\frac{x^2+5}{x^3+3x}}dx=\int\frac{x^2+5}{x(x^2+3)}dx=\int\bigg(\frac{5}{3x}-\frac{2x}{3(x^2+3)}\bigg)dx = \int\frac{5}{3x}dx-\int\frac{2x}{3(x^2+3)}dx$$

$$=$$

$$\int\frac{5}{3x}dx-\int\frac{2x}{3(x^2+3)}dx = \frac{5}{3}\int \frac{1}{x}dx-\frac{2}{3}\int\frac{x}{x^2+3}$$

Substitute $u=x^2 + 3 \to dx = \frac{1}{2x}du$ which means that :

$$\int \frac{x}{x^2+3}\to\int \frac{1}{2u}du$$

Solving both the integral parts and substituting back, you'll finally get :

$$\int{\frac{x^2+5}{x^3+3x}}dx=-\dfrac{\ln\left(x^2+3\right)-5\ln\left(\left|x\right|\right)}{3}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** I think partial fractioning may not be the *best* way depending on your criteria but it is a common practice:

$$\frac{x^2+5}{x^3+3x} = \frac{A}{x}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+3}$$

From here, you can easily see that $C=0$ and we also have $A+B = 1$ and $3A = 5$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Why $Bx+C$? I have watched some tutorials and never found something like that.

Comment: See example 3 here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PartialFractions.aspx. It depends on the expression in the denominator.

Comment: I tried to verify and I don't see any mistake. Also see http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%2F%283x%29-2x%2F%283x%5E2%2B9%29

Answer (score 1):

Let us try an approach where we will try to avoid explicitly finding a partial fraction decomposition.

Let
$$I = \int \frac{x^2 + 5}{x^3 + 3x} \, dx.$$
Now
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \frac{(x^2 - 3) + 8}{x^3 + 3x} \,dx\\
&= \int \frac{x^2 - 3}{x^2 \left (x + \dfrac{3}{x} \right )} \, dx + 8 \int \frac{dx}{x^3 + 3x}\\
&= \int \frac{1 - \frac{3}{x^2}}{x + \frac{3}{x}} \, dx + 8 \int \frac{dx}{x^3 + 3x}.
\end{align*}
Enforcing a substitution of $u = x + 3/x$ gives
$$I = \int \frac{du}{u} + \int \frac{dx}{x^3 + 3x} = \ln|u| + \int \frac{dx}{x^3 + 3x} = \ln \left |x + \frac{3}{x} \right | + 8 \int \frac{dx}{x^3 + 3x}. \tag1$$

Now consider
$$2I = 2 \int \frac{x^2 + 5}{x^3 + 3x} \, dx.$$
Writing the numerator as the derivative of the denominator we have
\begin{align*}
2I &= 2 \int \frac{\frac{1}{3} (3x^2 + 15)}{x^3 + 3x} \, dx\\
&= 2 \int \frac{\frac{1}{3} (3x^2 + 3) + 4}{x^3 + 3x} \, dx\\
&= \frac{2}{3} \int \frac{3x^2 + 3}{x^3 + 3x} \, dx + 8 \int \frac{dx}{x^3 + 3x}\\
&= \frac{2}{3} \ln |x^3 + 3x| + 8 \int \frac{dx}{x^3 + 3x} \tag2
\end{align*}
Subtracting (2) from (1) gives
$$I = \frac{2}{3} \ln |x^3 + 3x| - \ln \left |\frac{x^2 + 3}{x} \right | + C,$$
or after simplifying
$$\int \frac{x^2 + 5}{x^3 + 3x} \, dx = \frac{5}{3} \ln |x| - \frac{1}{3} \ln (x^2 + 3) + C.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using logarithmic integration, write the integral as:

$$\frac{1}{3} \int \frac{3x^2+3}{x^3+3x} \ dx + \int \frac{4}{x^3+3x} \ dx$$

and since $(x^2+3)(1) + x(-x) = 3$, $(x^2+3)(\frac{4}{3}) + x(-\frac{4}{3}x) = 4$, so this equals:

$$\frac{1}{3} \int \frac{3x^2+3}{x^3+3x} \ dx + \int \frac{4/3}{x} + \frac{(-4/3)x}{x^2+3} \ dx$$

$$= \frac{1}{3} \ln |x^3 + 3x| + \frac{4}{3} \ln |x| - \frac{2}{3} \ln|x^2+3| + C$$

which can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{1}{3} \ln |x| + \frac{1}{3} \ln |x^2 + 3| + \frac{4}{3} \ln |x| - \frac{2}{3} \ln|x^2+3| = \frac{5}{3} \ln |x| - \frac{1}{3} \ln|x^2+3|+ C.$$